# Adding single image after a specific list item

Tags: html, css

This is perhaps a bit of a silly question but getting my around certain css styling. I want to add a image targeting specific li item.

This will add the image after all the li items.

```
.menuStyling li:after{
 content: url('../img/arrowActive.png');
}
```

Which would be the best way to target one li item only?

Comment: Give that list item an ID or special class so that you can select it specifically.

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/mcawqbsv/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `nth-child` selector,  like this:

```
.menuStyling li:nth-child(2):after{
 content: url('../img/arrowActive.png');
}
```

where the 2nd `<li>` will have the image.

see more on nth-child [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

see a snippet below

```css
.menuStyling li:nth-child(2):after {
  content: " this is after child  list item 2";
  color: green
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuStyling">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `nth-child` selector to select your specific `li`, then `:after` to put data after.

```css
.menuStyling li:nth-child(2):after {
  content: url('http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/feed.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuStyling">
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>bar</li>
  <li>baz</li>
  <li>hello</li>
</ul>
```